# How to use Persian jalali calandar with js format in shiny app

Tags: javascript, css, shiny

I want to use persian jalali calendar in my shiny app to select date. I didn't find this capability in dateInput() function to show jalali calendar, moreover I didn't find any similar question for resolving this issue. But I found a persian jalali calendar file provided in javascrip (js)   with its CSS formats [here](https://github.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker)  . I tried to incorporate this files in my code but they didn't work. 
first of all I find dateInput() function code and changed its name to MYdateInput function as follows:

```
 library(htmltools)

MYdateInput <- function(inputId, label, value = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL,
                      format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "day", weekstart = 0,
                      language = "en", width = NULL, autoclose = TRUE,
                      datesdisabled = NULL, daysofweekdisabled = NULL) {

  value <- dateYMD(value, "value")
  min <- dateYMD(min, "min")
  max <- dateYMD(max, "max")
  datesdisabled <- dateYMD(datesdisabled, "datesdisabled")

  value <- restoreInput(id = inputId, default = value)

  tags$div(id = inputId,
           class = "shiny-date-input form-group shiny-input-container",
           style = if (!is.null(width)) paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),

           shinyInputLabel(inputId, label),
           tags$input(type = "text",
                      class = "form-control",
                      `data-date-language` = language,
                      `data-date-week-start` = weekstart,
                      `data-date-format` = format,
                      `data-date-start-view` = startview,
                      `data-min-date` = min,
                      `data-max-date` = max,
                      `data-initial-date` = value,
                      `data-date-autoclose` = if (autoclose) "true" else "false",
                      `data-date-dates-disabled` =
                        # Ensure NULL is not sent as `{}` but as 'null'
                        jsonlite::toJSON(datesdisabled, null = 'null'),
                      `data-date-days-of-week-disabled` =
                        jsonlite::toJSON(daysofweekdisabled, null = 'null')
           ),
           datePickerDependency
  )
}



# Make user-supplied dates are either NULL or can be coerced
# to a yyyy-mm-dd formatted string. If a date is specified, this
# function returns a string for consistency across locales.
# Also, `as.Date()` is used to coerce strings to date objects
# so that strings like "2016-08-9" are expanded to "2016-08-09"
dateYMD <- function(date = NULL, argName = "value") {
  if (!length(date)) return(NULL)
  if (length(date) > 1) warning("Expected `", argName, "` to be of length 1.")
  tryCatch(date <- format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m-%d"),
           error = function(e) {
             warning(
               "Couldn't coerce the `", argName,
               "` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd",
               call. = FALSE
             )
           }
  )
  date
}


shinyInputLabel <- function(inputId, label = NULL) {
  tags$label(
    label,
    class = "control-label",
    class = if (is.null(label)) "shiny-label-null",
    `for` = inputId
  )
}
```

then I changed the code of datePickerDependency as follows to define dependent js and css files of calendar:

```
datePickerDependency <- htmlDependency(name = "date-picker", version = "0.1",

                   src = getwd(),
                   script = c("www/bootstrap-datepicker.fa.js","www/bootstrap-datepicker.fa.min.js",
                              "www/bootstrap-datepicker.js","www/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"),
                   stylesheet = c("www/bootstrap-datepicker.css", "www/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css")
    )
```

then I run shiny code as follows:

```
    library(shiny)


ui<-fluidPage(
   MYdateInput(inputId="date", "Select data")

)
server<-function(input,output){
 #getDate <- input$sDate     
  #getDate 
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

but after running app the jalali calandar can not be displayed. Actually I want jalali calendar displayed instead of Georgian calendar using a code similar following code but incorporated with the js jalali calendar file available in above link. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput(inputId="date", "Select data")
  )
server<-function(input,output){

}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am beginner in shiny but after many struggling with codes I found the solution. However a simple new question is derived which need to be answered (please see end of my solution to comment on my new question).

Solution:
first I summarized and changed demo.html code in above link as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- <title>jQuery UI Datepicker with Twitter Bootstrap Theme</title > -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
        <style>body{margin:2em}</style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--  <h1>jQuery UI Datepicker with Twitter Bootstrap Theme</h1> -->
       <!--  <form> -->

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="datepicker1">Datepicker with bootstrap icon button</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append">
                        <input id="datepicker1" class="input-small" type="text">
                        <button id="datepicker1btn" class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="datepicker4">Datepicker with change month/year (jQuery option)</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker4" />
                </div>
            </div>

       <!-- </form> -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.fa.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
                $("#datepicker1btn").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#datepicker1").focus();
                });
                $("#datepicker4").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

then I transferred the all files including css, png, js and also demo.html to a www folder. In bootstrap.min.css file I modify the address of png files (search with png you will find two png address) by leave the name of files alone without relative address. Then I made app.R file (this file should be outside of www) as follows:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       htmlTemplate("www/demo.html"),
       dateInput("date","select date"),
       #Enter Submit to write info to file
       actionButton(inputId = "submit", "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL)

     ),

     mainPanel(
       # Application title
       titlePanel("Read Date"),

       column(2,
              verbatimTextOutput("dateText1"),
              verbatimTextOutput("dateText2"))

       )
     )
   )


server<-function(input,output){

  observeEvent(input$submit,{

     output$dateText1  <- renderText({
      paste("Georgian date is", as.character(input$date))
    })

    output$dateText2 <- renderText({
      paste("Jalali date is", as.character(input$datepicker1))
    })

  })
}  

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

After running app you can see two selection options for Jalali calendar and also the common calendar text box (End of solution).

[image]

But now I have my new question:
I want the selected dates to be displayed in main panel after click on submit bottom. As you can see it works well for Georgian calendar re-actively, but in the case of Jalali calendar it not works. I want by changing Jalali date the selected date be displayed on main panel. I Appropriate any help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript function
[Credit to this contributor](https://www.al-habib.info/islamic-calendar/hijricalendartext.htm)

```
function hijricalendar(adjust,year,month,day){
var today = new Date(year,month-1,day);

/*correction by Kamel to be reviewed*/
if (year <1970) {adjust=-3};

/*************************************/

if(adjust) {
adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24*adjust;
todaymili = today.getTime()+adjustmili;
today = new Date(todaymili);
}
day = today.getDate();
month = today.getMonth();
year = today.getFullYear();
m = month+1;
y = year;
if(m<3) {
y -= 1;
m += 12;
}

a = Math.floor(y/100.);
b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
if(y<1583) b = 0;
if(y==1582) {
if(m>10) b = -10;
if(m==10) {
b = 0;
if(day>4) b = -10;
}
}

jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

b = 0;
if(jd>2299160){
a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
}
bb = jd+b+1524;
cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
month = ee-1;
if(ee>13) {
cc += 1;
month = ee-13;
}
year = cc-4716; 
wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;
iyear = 10631./30.;
epochastro = 1948084;
epochcivil = 1948085;

shift1 = 8.01/60.;
z = jd-epochastro;
cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
z = z-10631*cyc;
j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
iy = 30*cyc+j;
z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
if(im==13) im = 12;
id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

var myRes = new Array(8);

myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

return myRes;
}
```

Comment: Dear Kemal thanks for your answer, but this answer is not relevant to Shiny app. My challenge is how to incorporate the calendar in attached above link which includes CSS files into shiny code structure to produce a date Range Input widget with persian calendar.

Comment: In the package found in github, you can use the index.html file, and keep the datepicker you want from there